# Create PageBlockTable With Two Types Of SObject

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable, table

I am trying to create a table in VisualForce that has both filters for the X and Y axis. Is this possible? For example: accountId 12345 has both tasks and notes. I want to be able to view both tasks and notes for this account in the same table. Thank you! [image: Table data for one account id]

Comment: Can you explain in more depth the data structure? Are you always going to have the same number of notes and tasks?

Comment: No, there is no limit on the amount of tasks or notes. I want the table to auto populate with all of the accounts tasks or notes that were created. So there could be 1 or there could be 100.

Comment: But you want to strictly alternate them? Why not just do two separate tables? All notes first, then all tasks. Seems much simpler to implement.

Comment: We actually already have the functionality of two different tables. But management would like to see both tasks and notes all in one table and they want them to be listed under one another. My guess is they want it this way for ease of viewing.  Do you think it would be possible to do this customization?

Comment: It *can* be accomplished, but a lot is left up to the imagination in your currently stated requirements. How do you figure out which `Task` to layer under which `Note`? What happens if you have more notes than tasks or vice versa?

Comment: I supposed the alternating is not as important as just getting them all in one list. I could do all the Notes first then list all of the Tasks underneath or vise versa. If we did it this way, it would look the same as two tables but it would be combined into one list which is fine. End goal is to just get them into one table.

Comment: Well that certainly simplifies things. The alternation is definitely a complicating factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a `List<SObject>` property. Your controller should look something like:

```
public with sharing class MyController
{
    public List<SObject> tasksAndNotes { get; private set; }
    public MyController()
    {
        tasksAndNotes = new List<SObject>();
        tasksAndNotes.addAll([SELECT ... FROM Task WHERE ...]);
        tasksAndNotes.addAll([SELECT ... FROM Note WHERE ...]);
    }
}
```

You can use a more sophisticated strategy to layer them in if you want.

Your markup would then look something like the below (`002` is the key prefix for `Note`).

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!tasksAndNotes}" var="record">
    <apex:column headerValue="Title/Subject">
        <apex:variable var="field" value="{!IF(BEGINS(record.Id, '002'), 'Title', 'Subject')}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!record[field]}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Body/Comment">
        <apex:variable var="field" value="{!IF(BEGINS(record.Id, '002'), 'Body', 'Description')}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!record[field]}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Created Date">
        <apex:outputField value="{!record['CreatedDate']}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Created By">
        <apex:outputField value="{!record['CreatedById']}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I like Larson's answer above, I think it is better to organize the data in the Apex layer, and minimize the logic in the presentation/VF layer.

In this case, you could make a custom object (not an "S" object) in apex that has the data exactly as you want it, with the interleaved rows.  Then deliver the data to PageBlockTable... no variable tags would be needed, and you'd be manipulating the data with a more powerful language (apex).

here are links on wrapper objects specifically for the purpose of delivering additional columns (a checkbox) or additional rows (account child records) to Visual Force pages:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000096tcIAA